# Using regex to verify an int, my way isnt working

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to make sure a string is a legal `int`.  This means that it must be a number (with no ".").  However, spaces *are* allowed both at the beginning as well as after the legal value.  The following examples illustrate:

```
"53" - good.
"5 " - good.
" 5" - good.
"5 3" - bad
```

I tried `(\\d|-\\d| \\d| -\\d)+`

Comment: what about `" 5 "`, good or bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
^\\s*([+-]?\\d+)\\s*$
```

The `^` matches the beginning of a string,

The `\\s*` accounts for any trailing spaces,

The `[+-]?` accounts for possible signs

The `$` ensures it's the end of the string.

As pointed out by @Dukeling, you don't need the anchors (`^` and `$`) if you use `matches()`.

Comment: The `^` and `$` are unneeded (assuming you use `matches()`).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use regex? You can use `Integer.parseInt(myString)` and catch the `NumberFormatException`.

```
try
{
  Integer.parseInt(myString.trim());   // trim removes leading and trailing whitespace
  //Will work for "53", " 5" and "5 "
  System.out.println(myString+ " is an integer.");
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex)
{
  System.out.println(myString+ " is not an integer.");
}
```

Comment: the question says _"Using regex to verify.."_

Comment: @fGo: that's the title, but the crux of the problem seems to be: `I want to make sure a string is a legal int` - and a regex isn't the only way to skin _that_ cat.

Comment: Note that `trim()` does not trim Unicode spaces. It actually removes everything below and including code point U+0020, which means it removes (most of) the control characters and space (ASCII 32).